# Why is this prototype field taking precedence over the same object field?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm in the process of learning Javascript prototypes and trying to understand why this is happening. It's my understanding that when looking for the value of a property, the object is checked before any prototype. When then, does this print "brown"?

```
function Box(item) {
    this.item = item;
}

Box.prototype.color = "brown";
Box.color = "blue";

var box = new Box(null);
console.log(box.color);

>>> brown
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Box.color = "blue";` assigns a property to the **function** `Box`, not to an instance of it. You can easily verify that by running `console.dir(box)` and `console.dir(Box)`.

If you want to assign the property to an instance, you have to create the instance first:

```
Box.prototype.color = "brown";

var box = new Box(null);
box.color = "blue"
```

or assign it inside the constructor function:

```
function Box(item) {
    this.item = item;
    this.color = 'blue';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `Box.color` is the constructor's property, it will never assigned to a instance object. After you initialize the `box` object, it only gets `this.item` and `prototype.color` property.